# Django mail not working in case of signal only

Tags: python, django

```
    TypeError at /admin/api/staff/4/change/
    object of type 'Staff' has no len()
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/api/staff/4/change/
    Django Version: 2.2.11
    Exception Type: TypeError
    Exception Value:    
    object of type 'Staff' has no len()
    Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.5/email/_parseaddr.py in getaddrlist, line 252
    Python Executable:  /home/fractaluser/Desktop/upwork/paul/env/bin/python
    Python Version: 3.5.2
    Python Path:    
    ['/home/fractaluser/Desktop/upwork/paul',
    '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
    '/home/fractaluser/Desktop/upwork/paul/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
    Server time:    Sun, 15 Mar 2020 05:39:20 +0000


    @receiver(post_save, sender=Staff)
    def hear_signal(sender, instance , **kwargs):
        if kwargs["created"]:
            return

        # mail([instance], "name")
        return



def mail(list, name):
    from smtplib import SMTP,SMTPAuthenticationError,SMTPException
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 587
    username = ""
    password = ""
    from_email= username
    to_list=list

    try:
        email_conn = SMTP(host, port)
        email_conn.ehlo()
        email_conn.starttls()
        email_conn.login(username,password)
        the_msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
        the_msg['subject'] ="Sponsorshop approval"
        the_msg["from"]=from_email
        plain_txt = "testing the message"
        html_text = '<h1>Hello</h1>'
        part_1 = MIMEText(plain_txt,'plain')
        part_2 = MIMEText(html_text,"html")
        the_msg.attach(part_1)
        the_msg.attach(part_2)
        email_conn.sendmail(from_email,to_list,the_msg.as_string())
        email_conn.quit()
    except SMTPException as sm:
        print(sm)
```

Here is my code.

I am trying to send a mail when my Staff models gets updates or created.
The same mail is working fine incase of email verification in case of login or register.
but, throwing error in the signal  @receiver.

Can't we send mail in @receiver method. Or is there any way to achive that ? 
I wants to send a mail when my model updated.

Please have a look .

Comment: Share your Staff model

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you want to send the mail whether the model instance is created or updated you need to keep the definition of signal like this.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Staff)
def hear_signal(sender, instance ,**kwargs):
    mail([instance], "name")
```

And in mail function you are sending staff instance as **to** argument instead of staff instance's mail.

Let's say your Staff model has an email field then you need to modify your receiver signal as

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Staff)
def hear_signal(sender, instance ,**kwargs):
    mail([instance.email], "name")
```